# How to reset a form to its original state?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a vb.net windows application. In this I have a windows form which has few textboxes and few controls on it. Now after loading the form I create and remove few controls in that form. I also have a reset button on the form so user can click on it an can get the original design of the form. I tried to call InitializeComponents() method. But It doesn't reflect any changes on the form. How to get my original design on button click?

Alright, I need to modify my question. I don't want to redesign my all the controls but only the treeview which I have modified.

Answer (score 2):

The "original" state/settings of a Windows Form is not tracked anywhere. The modifications you make at runtime (adding, resizing, removing, etc. controls) all happen in real-time and become the current and *only* state of the form.

You could keep track of the original settings yourself and then write code to loop through all of the controls and restore them, but that would be a lot of work.

The easier solution is to just destroy the current form and replace it with a newly-created one. Of course, when a new form is created, it will have the *default* state, which is exactly what you want.

---

**Edit:** Calling `InitializeComponents()` is not a perfect solution. There's a reason it isn't called `ReinitializeComponents()`. It is designed to do the *initial* initialization when the form is first created and displayed. It was not designed to be called again elsewhere by client code. If you do so anyway, it's going to clobber things up.

If tree nodes are the only thing you're worried about preserving, why not declare a class-level member to hold the ones you delete? You can use something like a [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) or [`Stack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) collection to hold them after they are deleted, and pop them back out when you want to restore them to the TreeView.

Comment: Actually I have a treeview on the form. Now originally that treeview had lets say 10 nodes, I removed 5 nodes. Now before calling InitializeComponents() there are 5 nodes in the tree and after calling the method I can see in immediate windows there are 10 nodes in the tree. But the only problem is it doesn't show on the form. I also used me.refresh() method but didn't work either. And I also lose all the associated events too.

Comment: thanks for the explanation bout InitializeComponent Cody. You are right its just a matter of treeview. But then How can I do it? Lemme read about this Queue and stack collections.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub resetform(ByVal form_name as Form)  
    form_name.dispose  
    form_name.show
End Sub
```

call the resetform on your button click event

```
resetform(YourFormName)
```

Comment: Ok lemme edit my question here. I don't want my all the controls to be redesign but only the treeview. How can I do it?

Comment: so your treeview contains something from the start? Then you want to reset it to that value after changes has been made am I correct?

Comment: yaa lemme explain what happens. Treeview actually contains the name of the several reports. Now user has selected few of them as their favorites. Now My treeview has 100 reports initially. Now on load I call LoadFavorites function which removes all the extra reports. So users see only their favorites. But there is a button called Show all reports. Now when users click on that they should be able to see all the names again. Hope I was clear in the question.

Comment: Have you tried putting the code for populating your treeview to show all reports on a separated SUB? You can then call it whenever you want that way. Can you post your code on how you populate your treeview?

Comment: Thats the thing. I didnt populate my tree with code. Otherwise I could simply call it. But all the nodes are added while designing.

Comment: You should convert the way you populate the treeview to codes. It will be more efficient in the long run.

Comment: thats what I think I will have to do. Coz I tried all most everything copy the original tree to a variable and assigning it back on show all. But whenever I remove nodes from original it also removes from the copy. Do you have any idea about that? If yes then it must work. I also tried TreenodeCollection but the same result.

Comment: I don't know about storing it to a variable but you can save it to an XML file.  Check this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308063

Answer (score 0):

I just worked around and its done now. I took a variable as treenode and assigned with Clone of the original treeview. Finally just add that variable to my treeview.

Comment: Careful with this. The [`Clone` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.clone.aspx) produces *shallow* copies, so if you delete the TreeNode items when you remove them from the TreeView, you may lose them completely. You need to take care that you don't encounter subtle bugs and unexpected garbage collection behavior.

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray actually you are right, thats what happened. But then I didn't find any solution so had to work with 2 treeviews.